# data sync on aws ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Hi i am trying to sync the data from one main `ec2` instances to all the running `ec2` instances. Something like a button click can also do the operation. I am able to get the list of running `ec2` instances through the `aws php sdk`. Is something like this possible through the sdk? Or what are the alternatives?

Comment: Can you be little descriptive on what you mean by syncing the data ? Yes, using AWS PHP SDK you can list the running instances. But looking at what you want, you are better off using EC2 API and AMI tools and use the command "ec2-describe-instances" to list your instances

Comment: Thanks for the response. What I am trying to achieve is get to see a list of all running ec2 instances. Once i update/add a file to my main ec2 instance, i want the other running instances also get updated with the same data as on the main instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here are some ways to achieve what you are asking.

1) If only file sync is your problem, use a network sharing protocol like NFS. Let the main instance host the NFS server and all the other instances act as NFS client and mount the endpoint exposed by NFS Server. In that way, when you place the file it is shared. Mind that, for this to work efficiently and securely, it should be on the same AWS region. There might be some negligible lag if the instances themselves are spread across multiple availability zones.

2) If you are looking at syncing file, packages, etc. use a configuration Management tool like Chef/Puppet. Using Chef, you can ensure that all your instances are in sync. The Good thing is that the instances can be geographically located, the con is the learning curve involved in using these tools.

Comment: thanks for the response, are their any open source options available?

Comment: @ntidote - both the above options are opensource.

Comment: I have checked for Puupet/Chef at http://www.opscode.com/products/ , http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/how-to-buy/ (in case of puppet , 10 nodes are supporte for free).

Comment: can you provide some link/tutorials for nfs ??

Comment: depending on the linux distro., the package names might change. Googling will reveal ample resources on how to do this. Ex: In debain/ubuntu, this link http://slacklabs.be/networking/tutorial-setting-up-nfs-on-debian-linux shows how to do it. Remember, you should use the internal ip's.